# Create REST data source to access sql server database for an oracle apex application?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, api, rest, oracle-apex

I am trying to build an Oracle APEX application which consumes data of an Sql Server Database.

I was told I needed to build an API over the sql server database and then access it with Apex.

From the documentation I read, Types of APIs (REST data sources) that can be used in APEX are :

- Simple http
- Oracle REST Data Services
- Oracle Cloud Applications (SaaS) REST Service
- Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) REST Service

How can I build such an API? Can I use Microsoft SQL Management Studio for this task since i'm not a developper?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle APEX will let you consume data via a web service exposed by SQL Server so you have to figure out how to do that since the data resides in SQLServer. -This is not an Oracle APEX function-

If you wanted to expose SQLServer data in Oracle then you need something like Oracle Gateway for SQLServer which will let you access data in SQLServer seemlesly.

Other options would be Gluent or similar products (and most likely insanly expensive).